# 'LUTTER_TOOL_ARGSsnapshot_path*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Tags: dart, flutter

I am facing this issue while upgrading flutter from v0.4.4

Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112]

To

Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112], locale en-IN)

Logs:

```
E:\projects\xxx>flutter upgrade
Upgrading Flutter from E:\Installed\flutter...
From https://github.com/flutter/flutter
   f9bb4289e..c7ea3ca37  beta                   -> origin/beta
 * [new branch]          Hixie-patch-1          -> origin/Hixie-patch-1
 * [new branch]          abarth-patch-1         -> origin/abarth-patch-1
   6c03a3f96..020e0ef55  dev                    -> origin/dev
 * [new branch]          flutter_module         -> origin/flutter_module
   677df7c35..a18f5e84a  master                 -> origin/master
 * [new branch]          regenAndroidFiles      -> origin/regenAndroidFiles
 * [new branch]          revert-18465-skippaint -> origin/revert-18465-skippaint
 * [new tag]             v0.5.0                 -> v0.5.0
 * [new tag]             v0.5.1                 -> v0.5.1
 * [new tag]             v0.5.2                 -> v0.5.2
 * [new tag]             v0.5.3                 -> v0.5.3
 * [new tag]             v0.5.4                 -> v0.5.4
 * [new tag]             v0.5.5                 -> v0.5.5

Checking out files: 100% (273/273), done.
Updating f9bb4289e..c7ea3ca37
 .../fake-extension.txt                             |   0
 271 files changed, 7793 insertions(+), 1685 deletions(-)

Upgrading engine...
Checking Dart SDK version...
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 1ed25ca7b7e3e3e8047df050bba4174074c9b336...
Unzipping Dart SDK...
Updating flutter tool...
Downloading package sky_engine...

Flutter 0.4.4 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f9bb4289e9 (6 weeks ago) • 2018-05-29 21:07:33 +0200
Engine • revision 1ed25ca7b7
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58

Running "flutter packages upgrade" in team...               22.8s

Running flutter doctor...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
'LUTTER_TOOL_ARGSsnapshot_path*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `flutter upgrade` once more, you will not get `LUTTER_TOOL_ARGSsnapshot_path*` error anymore.